# Set Theory: Is there an infinite set of sets satisfying those conditions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there an infinite set of sets $\{ X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfying those conditions?

1. For all integer $k \in [1, \infty]$, $\bigcup\{ X_n\}_{n=1}^k = \emptyset$.
2. $\bigcup\{ X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \neq \emptyset$.

So the finite union is empty but infinite union is not empty. I am thinking this inductively but can not imagine the infinite union. There is no constraint about the element $X_n$.

Comment: Suppose the union of all the $X_n$'s was nonempty. What can you say about an element in this union?

Comment: Oh right, such element must belong to the some X...

Answer (score 2):

No way, such a family of sets cannot exist.

Indeed, let $x \in \bigcup X_n$. Then, by definition of union, $x$ belongs to some of the $X_n$, say $X_N$. Then, it belongs to the finite union $X_1 \cup \dots \cup X_N$.